# Will custom annotations be implemented someday?

Tags: annotations

So I know it's not possible that we create our own annotations at this point. I just wonder if this will be possible someday? Is it on a roadmap somewhere? Does somebody know something?

I would also be interested in why Salesforce does not support custom annotations at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's unlikely anyone besides someone in product development at Salesforce could answer that. Setting that aside, what do you mean by custom annotations? Are you thinking about something like `@future` or `@auraenabled`? What do you envision such a feature to be able to do?

Comment: What I meant by that is that we could roll our own annotations like in other languages (e.g. Java). Right now I don't have a use case in mind but over the years I had a couple of situations where this would have been quite handy. I'll update my question with an example when I stumble upon another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nonexistent annotations (e.g. PMD uses this to suppress PMD warnings), but they won't have any special functionality. Like Generics, it is unlikely that we will have them in the foreseeable future, as they are of relatively limited use in Apex. You can look at the [various annotations customers have requested](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/search?type=Ideas&keywords=annotations), though I couldn't find one specifically for custom annotations. Of course, this may change in the future, but I have not heard of any plans to support this at this time.

Comment: Oh wow. There are some really great examples in there. But before annotations, I would die to get generics first. Sometimes it's hard to work in Apex without all the nice features I'm accustomed to from other languages. Oh well. We only waited almost 10 years for a switch statement so this will probably take around 20 years.